# Trouble updating user language field in MySQL database using PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am seeking your help because I am having trouble updating the user's language field in the MySQL database using a PHP form on a web page. The PHP script owner has read and write permissions for the database.

Despite receiving a positive feedback from

```
if ( update_user_meta( $user_id, 'LanguagesUser', $LanguagesUser )
```

the field in the database is not updated when the user submits the form.

Has anyone experienced this issue before, and if so, were you able to resolve it?

```
global $current_user;
global $wpdb;
$url = site_url();
// Tables
// Using $wpdb->prefix for table prefix
$table_users = "users";
$user_id = get_current_user_id();?>
<p>
<form method="post">
<!-- Field for language -->
<label for="LanguagesUser">Languages* : </label>
<input type="text" id="LanguagesUser" name="LanguagesUser" value="<?php echo um_user('LanguagesUser'); ?>" required>

                    <!-- Button to submit the form -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </form>
            </p>
            <?php

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                // Check if required data has been submitted
                if ( ! isset( $_POST['LanguagesUser'] ) || empty( $_POST['LanguagesUser'] ) ) {
                    // The field is empty, display an error message
                    echo '<p class="error">The "Languages" field is required</p>';
                } else {
                    // If the data has been submitted, retrieve and validate it
                    $LanguagesUser = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['LanguagesUser'] );

                    // Update the "LanguagesUser" user profile field in the database
                    if ( update_user_meta( $user_id, 'LanguagesUser', $LanguagesUser ) ) {
                        echo '<p class="success">The languages have been successfully updated for the user with ID '.$user_id.'</p>';
                    } else {
                        error_log( 'Database update failed for user with ID '.$user_id );
                    }
                }
```

I have been trying to allow a WordPress user to update their language profile using a form. The script I'm using has global variables for the current user and the WordPress database, and also retrieves the site URL. The form contains a field for the user to enter their language and a submit button. When the user submits the form, the script checks if the field is empty or not, sanitizes the input data, and then attempts to update the user's language field in the database using the "update_user_meta" function. Despite receiving a positive feedback from this function, the language field in the database is not being updated. Therefore, I am seeking help on how to troubleshoot this issue. Thank you.

Comment: _"The PHP script owner has read and write permissions for the database."_ - that already makes little sense to begin with. You don't access a database using any "script owners", you access it using a database user when making a database connection.

Comment: _"the language field in the database is not being updated"_ - have you really checked that directly in the database table, or are you simply drawing that conclusion from something else?

Comment: Indeed, I managed to update the user's language field in the MySQL database using the form. I have realised that I was too hasty in drawing this conclusion, and I will now explore the configuration of the 'LanguagesUser' field in the Ultimate Member form. So this is a new topic to investigate. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I finally found a way around this problem by adapting the input field by first checking if the variable $LanguagesUser exists using the isset() function. If it does, its value is displayed, otherwise the input field remains empty : `<input type="text" id="LanguagesUser" name="LanguagesUser" value="<?php if (isset($LanguagesUser)) { echo $LanguagesUser; } ?>" required>`
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your help and prompt response!
Indeed, you are correct in your earlier statement that the script is executed by a user, rather than a owner. This particular user has the necessary permissions to perform the update operation on the database.
I have indeed verified that the field for this particular user is present in the database table using a MySQL command : `SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = 1327 AND meta_key = 'LanguagesUser';`

Furthermore, I am able to access this field, corresponding to the user, via the WordPress dashboard, under the "users" section, where I can view and edit their profile. However, despite being able to modify the content of this field using a form, any changes made do not seem to have any impact on the corresponding field in the database.